# can't build visual studio project with vcpkg manifest mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcpkg

I'm trying to use Visual studio with vcpkg manifest mode to practice c++, without CMake.
This is what I've tried:

- Install VS2022 with standard c++ support.
- Install vcpkg, do vcpkg integrate
- Create the template hello world project.
- Turn on vcpkg manifest mode on visual studio project setting.
- Add `vcpkg.json` file in the same directory where `.sln` file exists.

This is my `vcpkg.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

- Press Ctrl+F5 to build

And the error says:

```
Error   MSB3073 ""C:\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe" install  --x-wait-for-lock --triplet "x64-windows" --vcpkg-root "C:\vcpkg\\" "--x-manifest-root=C:\Test\\" "--x-install-root=C:\Test\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\\" " 
명령이 종료되었습니다(코드: 1). Test    C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\msbuild\vcpkg.targets 183
```

Sorry for the Korean. It means "Command terminated (Code: 1)".
It seems the error message does not contains any useful information, at least for me. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your  build output and there will  be :Identifiers must be lowercase alphanumeric+hypens

Use "test" in your json file.